# Regression and RDD give results in opposite directions but both statistically significant

Tags: econometrics, regression, causality, causal-inference

I am conducting an RDD on an attitude and how it shifts over time due to a shock (sharp RD measured in days), I am using RDROBUST in STATA. I do not think I have coding errors but I need help understanding why my RD result gives a positive coefficient for the days variable, but when I run a regression the coefficient for the days variable becomes negative? Is this normal? Should I run some diagnostics? If so which do you recommend? Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the RDD to pin down the effect of the shock instead of allowing endogeneity to bias the effect estimate in a more naïve regression model?